# POST to Java from Wordpress

Tags: java, wordpress, post, jakarta-ee, wicket

My page used to be all java with Wicket as front-end. Now, I have a wordpress start-page with a loginform. When I enter the email and password in that loginform, I want to redirect it to a login-service which then redirects the user to the wicket welcome-page if login is successful.

The way I have tried to do this is by sending a POST message from the wordpress page, and handle it with a Service in my java application. This doesn't work well for me.

**Is this even a good way to do it?** If not, what other ways are possible?

This is the implementation I have attempted today:

(simulation of the post-action from the wordpress page on top)

```
<FORM action="http://localhost:8080/Login" method="post">
    <P>
    <LABEL for="email">Email: </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="email"><BR>
    <LABEL for="password">Password: </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="password"><BR>

    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
    </P>
 </FORM>
```

Service:

```
@Path("/Login")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService{

 private static final Response USER_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED = Response.status(
   Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).build();

 private static final Response USER_SUCCESSFULLY_AUTHORIZED = Response.status(
   Status.ACCEPTED).build();

 @Autowired
 private UserController userController;

 @Override
 @POST
 public Response login(@QueryParam("email") String email, 
   @QueryParam("password") String password) {

  boolean authenticated = userController.authenticate(email,
    password);
  User u = userController.findByEmail(email);

  if (u != null && u.getUserType() == UserType.COMPANY_RECRUITER) {
   handleCompanyRecruiter(u);
   return USER_SUCCESSFULLY_AUTHORIZED;
  } 
  else if ((authenticated && u != null) && (u.getCompany().getIsActive())) {
   signInUser(u);
   setCorrectResponsePage(u);
   return USER_SUCCESSFULLY_AUTHORIZED;
  }
  else{
   return USER_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED;
  }
 }
```

applicationContext:

```
 <!-- LOGIN SERVICE --> 
      <jaxrs:server id="loginService" address="/login">
      <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
       <ref bean="loginServiceBean" />
      </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <jaxrs:providers>
       <ref bean="jaxbProvider" />
       <ref bean="notFoundExceptionMapper" />
      </jaxrs:providers>
     </jaxrs:server>

<bean class="services.CandidateServiceImpl"
        id="candidateServiceBean" />
```

Running this, when I enter the form and press send I receive this error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/Login
```

Me annotating the LoginServiceImpl with @Path("/Login") is maybe not the right way? **How do I redirect the POST to the correct location?**

And this is the old Wicket-page for the login:

```
<wicket:panel>
<wicket:extend>       
    <div id="top_login">   
        <form wicket:id="loginForm">  
                <div>
                    <label for="loginEmail" wicket:id="loginEmailLabel">Email</label>
                    <input class="text" id="loginEmail" wicket:id="loginEmail" tabindex="101" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="loginPassword" wicket:id="loginPasswordLabel">Password</label>
                    <input class="text" type="password" id="loginPassword" wicket:id="loginPassword" tabindex="102" />
                </div>
                <div class="loginBtnArea">
                    <input wicket:id="loginButton" class="submit" type="submit" tabindex="103" value="Login" />

                </div>   
            </form> 
            <a wicket:id="forgotPasswordLink"><span class="forgotPassword" wicket:id="forgotPasswordLabel">Forgot your password?</span></a>                          
    </div>
</wicket:extend>
</wicket:panel>
```

Comment: why you want to use the wordpress start-page? Wicket should be good enough to support your welcome screen.

Comment: It's a business requirement I have no control of ... I agree that it is dumb.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the problem is in your config and not in the thought procedure itself.

Declare a bean with id **loginServiceBean** in your applicationContext.

EDIT:

I'm not wholly familiar with the techniques you are using, but could it be that the `@Consumes("application/xml")`-annotation blocks the request? You could try putting `@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`-annotation to your method, that is supposed to handle the login data.

Soure: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4867/ggqqr?a=view

EDIT^2:

Your form's action is `http://localhost:8080/Login`. If I understand correctly it ought to be `http://localhost:8080/Login/login`

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that helped me get past the applicationContext-error. I updated my post. The big problem is how to get the service talking with the java-code, and this is where I seem to struggle.

Comment: I tried using @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") but it produced the same 404-error. I also tried removing the @Consumes annotation alltogether, also receiveing the same 404 error.

Comment: I tried adding http://localhost:8080/Login/login to my forms action, but the error remains the same.